# Xamarin Studio contenues to freeze when trying to open an .axml file, and other .axml bugs

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android, freeze

So this problem is happening to me a ton and I can't believe there is not a mention of others having the same issue on the interwebs. In the course of working with Xamarin Android axil files, often I will double click one in the solutions pane and XS will stick , showing "Opening xxxxxxxxxxx.axml". The only way to get out of it is to restart XS. Right now I am doing some work that requires a single line alteration on about 30 different axml files and I have had this happen 9-10 times in the last 20 minutes. I have also had this bug happen on multiple Macs, with (obviously) separate installs of XS and it has been an issue for months. I am getting to my wits end.

On top of the above bug, I also get one that will prevent an edited axml from saving changes. So I will do a bunch of work on one, save it, close the tab out, and then open it again only to find that all the changes were not saved. I am to the point now that I have to select all, copy, close the file, open it, select all, paste and then save again, just to get my edits to save. I have lost SO MUCH time and work because of these bugs.

Is anyone having a similar experience? How can they be fixed?

Comment: bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: Done. https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52693